# iframe video (vimeo) disappears in safari 15.3

Tags: video, iframe, safari

I have an embedded Vimeo on this test page: https://florianwm.com/about-test/ which works fine in ff and chrome. In safari, the video disappears at the beginning since safari 15.3

This is the code:

```
<div class="responsive-video">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/432469406?background=1"
frameborder="0" playsinline style="border-radius: 15px;" webkitAllowFullScreen
mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, has anyone any idea why the video disappeares in safari? Thank you.